# Populating Pandas column with the use of reference values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

What's the easiest way in Pandas to check throughout whole 'Product' column if entries include 'Product ID', then use 'Arch ID' to populate 'Product Arch' column?

df1:

```
  Product Product Arch
0   P 1K2         None
1   PC200         None
2   Modem         None
3  SSD5AZ         None
```

df2:

```
  Product ID     Arch ID
0        1K2    Computer
1        D5A  Enterprise
```

Expected output:

```
  Product Product Arch
0   P 1K2         Computer
1   PC200         None
2   Modem         None
3  SSD5AZ         Enterprise
```

Trying different results for a few hours now, with no success. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex crafted from `df2` values as key to `merge`:

```
import re

df1['Product Arch'] = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1['Product'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(df2['Product ID'].map(re.escape))})", expand=False),
                                right_on='Product ID', how='left')['Arch ID']
```

Output:

```
  Product Product Arch
0   P 1K2     Computer
1   PC200          NaN
2   Modem          NaN
3  SSD5AZ   Enterprise
```

reproducible input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['P 1K2', 'PC200', 'Modem', 'SSD5AZ'],
                    'Product Arch': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Product ID': ['1K2', 'D5A'], 'Arch ID': ['Computer', 'Enterprise']})
```

Comment: Thanks! How would it need to look if the second row in 'Product ID' would change to 'D5A'?

Comment: throws an error `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: Have you checked the update?

Comment: Yes! But erroring out `TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, int found`

Comment: When I changed columns into str, then I just got blank 'Product Arch' rows

Comment: @letsgamble check my reproducible input that matches your question, it works fine with it. Can you provide an input in such a format that triggers your error? My guess is that your issue has nothing to do with this question, you might be loading your real data incorrectly.